# Visual Studio ASPX Files Synthax Highlight out of Wack

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I've just startedw working with ASP.NET MVC 2, and I have a question regarding ASPX syntax highligting in Visual Studio.

Often I want to generate some serverside content witin quotes, for example

```
<a href="<% c# code %>"> foo </a>
```

But Visual Studio highlights this incorrectly, causing warnings and other problems. See attached image, which shows `Url.Action` as string and "Collage" as object... Am I doing something silly here? Or is this how things are supposed to be?

http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/7898/screenuk.png

PS. I'm well aware about the unnecessary code duplication in the provided example. I just wanted to try something. And this is actually a big part of the problem, because when Visual Studio gets confused it confuses me too! If I were to generate those lines with a for loop, that highlights as a string, the code feels very messy.

Comment: Other than the unnecessary code duplication in the provided sample are you aware that it is better to use strongly typed views rather than `ViewData`?

Comment: Oh, I was afraid someone brought it up. Yes, I'll write ViewModels for everything... =)

Answer (score 0):

Due to a fundamental limitation in the VS editor, this unfortunately doesn't work